# Xamarin.Forms: how to set Images to get the expected result

Tags: image, layout, xamarin.forms, height, aspect-ratio

I'm looking for a good way to implement a control that looks like a **ListView with 2 columns**, where each column has distinct height. As I didn't found another solution, I've decided to do it through a **Repeater** [control](https://github.com/Martynnw/Trailmaker.UI/blob/master/Trailmaker.UI/Repeater.cs).

The expected result is something like this: 
[image: screenshot]

- All the items come from the **same DataSource**, and this DataSource will contain between one and a dozen of items.
- The items must be splitted **automatically** (by modulo) into the 2 columns
- When the user click on the button related to the item, this will open the item's detail page
- The red squares are **images that must have the same height/width**

I'm working on the design of the cell **DataTemplate**, but I didn't see how to manage the images:

- The distinction between the 2 columns is given by a Grid containing 2 Columns
- Then I specify the DataTemplate for each column

  ```
  <ScrollView>
      <Grid Padding="10">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <!-- Col.1 -->
          <tabletControls:Repeater  Grid.Column="0" Margin="10"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding ListProductItems}">
              <tabletControls:Repeater.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <ViewCell>
                          <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
                              <StackLayout>
                                  <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding Icon}" 
                                                    Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                              </StackLayout>
                              ...
                          </StackLayout>
                      </ViewCell>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </tabletControls:Repeater.ItemTemplate>
          </tabletControls:Repeater>

          <!-- Col.2 -->
          <tabletControls:Repeater  Grid.Column="1" Margin="10"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding ListProductItems}">
              <tabletControls:Repeater.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <ViewCell>
                          <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
                              <StackLayout>
                                  <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding Icon}" 
                                                    Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                              </StackLayout>
                              ...
                          </StackLayout>
                      </ViewCell>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </tabletControls:Repeater.ItemTemplate>
          </tabletControls:Repeater>
      </Grid>
  </ScrollView
  ```

But this doesn't work as expected, as the image's height/width are not the same:

[image: result]

I already tried to play with Aspect (AspectFill, AspectFit, Fill) or VerticalOptions/HorizontalOptions, withou any result...

***Is it possible to achieve the expected result without specify an HeightRequest? Are there other options?***

Comment: are the images all the size from the source?

Comment: @Jason I'm not sure, as I receive data from a WebService. On other Views, the images are displayed in "portrait" mode. Is this important if I want to display the images in "square" mode?

Comment: if the source images aren't square, and you don't specify a width/heigh, then they will never display as squares.  Why don't you want to use a Width/Height request?

Comment: Cause I don't know the expected Heigt/Width. The Width is given by the main Grid's Columns ratio : 2/3 and 1/3. So, the Width is defined from this, and I would like to "duplicate" the height from the given width...

Comment: Is there a way to update the HeightRequest taking into account the available width in the container?